# One to zero relationship (remove the foreign key from one side of the relationship) in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to have a one-to-zero relationship where a user has an image, but an image doesn't know about its user, so it is like it has zero users. Is this not the done thing? I don't see examples of how to do it. The examples always add a foreign key to both sides of the relationship. I have tried it like so:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Image ProfilePicture { get; set; }

}

public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsMain { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>(user =>
{
    user.HasKey(usr => usr.Id);
    user.HasOne(e => e.ProfilePicture);
});
```

But the ProfilePicture is not nullable, and it needs to be. I was going to have `Image` be in all sorts of different entities, so I didn't want to add the entity foreign key to it. Is that possible, and if so, is it silly, as it doesn't seem commonly done? I've already done it with a list of images on an entity using the Image class above:

```
public class VgnItm
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public List<int> Tags { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
}

public class VgnItmImage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(VgnItm)), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int VgnItmId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Image)), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public VgnItm VgnItm { get; set; }
}
modelBuilder.Entity<VgnItm>(vgnItm =>
{
    vgnItm.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator").IsUnique();
    vgnItm.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    vgnItm.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
    vgnItm.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    vgnItm.HasMany(e => e.Images) 
        .WithMany() 
        .UsingEntity<VgnItmImage>(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reuse my `Image` class without it needing to know the `User`, but I think the relationship has to be one to many with a join table in between even though I want one to one or zero. I am just using it like a "one to zero or one" by only adding one or zero images to each user. An important piece was using the "?" here to allow zero: `public int? ProfilePictureId { get; set; }`

Code:

```
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsMain { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public Image ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public int? ProfilePictureId { get; set; }
}

public class UserImage
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(User)), Column(Order = 0)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Image)), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>(user =>
{
    user.HasKey(usr => usr.Id);
    user.HasOne(u => u.ProfilePicture)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.ProfilePictureId);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<UserImage>(userImage =>
{
    userImage.HasIndex(g => new { g.UserId, g.ImageId }).IsUnique();
    userImage.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
});
```